# Upload files to aws s3 using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mean-stack

I am working on a project (based on MEAN Stack) which shows different images according to different logged in users. I am using amazon S3 for storing those images.

Currently I have creatde a different route for the admin panel where the admin can sign in and upload the images on amazon s3 for different users.(Also,is this the correct flow of the application?)

I have the below line of code in my js file:

```
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: xxxxxx, secretAccessKey: xxxxxx });
```

I have read that this should only be for development purposes and I should not be having my accesskeyId and  secretacesskey in the code like this.

I want to know that for production what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

For production you need to store these keys in environment. The Aws module will itself pick these from environment.
`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` keys should be set.
For example on local machine you can test these with terminal commands
`export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXX` and export `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXX` respectively.

For production you will need to do the same. Except you will need to do this via the node process manager you are using. Here is an example of pm2 process manager doing it.

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
      {
        name: "myapp",
        script: "./app.js",
        watch: true,
        instance_var: 'INSTANCE_ID',
        env: {
            "PORT": 3000,
            "NODE_ENV": "development",
            "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "XXXXX",
            "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "XXXXX" 
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/#specific-environment-variables
The flow is similar even if you are using a different process manager.